# What do the waveforms in a buck converter look like just after turn on?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, buck

Below is the circuit diagram of buck converter.

[image]

I am studying about the buck converter. What I observed is everywhere it is explained with the help of waveform in steady state.

I have a couple of questions:

1. What is stopping the capacitor from charging  up to Vin?
2. What does the capacitor waveform look like just after turn on?
3. What does the inductor waveform look like just after turn on?

Comment: 1. The limited duty cycle and the inductor. Google _DCM_ and _CCM_. 2. Please simulate and see for yourself. 3. See 2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *What is stopping the capacitor to charge up to Vin.*

The presence of the inductor and, the duty cycle being less than 100% prevents the capacitor charging to the full value of Vin. This is what buck converters do; they let energy through to the capacitor in a controlled way: -

- In the 1st charge cycle the voltage will only normally rise to a few percent of \$V_{IN}\$.
- Then, when the switch disengages, the capacitor continues to charge by swallowing up the stored energy from the inductor via the free-wheel diode.
- All the energy can be taken from the inductor and, the free-wheel diode prevents discharge back into the inductor.

.

- In the 2nd switching cycle, the capacitor begins charging from where it left off at the end of the 1st cycle.
- Subsequent cycles will raise the capacitor voltage up to the desired level and, at this point, an external control-loop (something that is needed) will regulate the duty cycle to ensure that \$V_{OUT}\$ remains at the desired value.

Here's the voltage waveform on the capacitor (no load and no closed-loop control): -

[image]

> *What does the capacitor waveform look like just after turn on?*

The charging capacitor voltage follows a square law; it gradually starts to rise and progressively, the slope gets steeper until the switch disengages. This is all over in a few microseconds normally: -

[image]

> *What does the inductor waveform look like just after turn on?*

The inductor's voltage waveform is the applied voltage (caused by the switch being engaged) minus the voltage waveform of the capacitor.

Comment: Very minor nit. "exponentially" -> exponentially decay towards Vin or the desired output voltage.

Comment: @horta no I really did mean what I said --> the capacitor voltage will exponentially rise towards the desired output voltage. I'll show a picture.

Comment: Ah ok. Due to the inductors desire for constant current action?

Comment: Check the simulation pictures @horta

Comment: @Andyaka,Thank you very much.May I know the name of the tool used for simulation.

Comment: @Hari it's called microcap

Answer (score 5):

> 1. What is stopping the capacitor from charging up to Vin?

Feedback. It adjusts the duty cycle (on-time of the switch over a switching period) dynamically. If duty-cycle goes 100% (i.e. fully on indefinitely) then the output cap will charge up to the input voltage. So if the switch doesn't open during start up then the capacitor voltage can rise up to the input level.

> 2. What does the capacitor waveform look like just after turn on?

It's basically an LC tank driven by a pulse. So, once the tank sees a fast ramp-up input voltage (an impulse) the output will start to oscillate and the oscillation won't stop even if the input voltage is zero. The oscillation will decay over time, of course. The amplitude of the oscillation and decaying time varies with component values and loading conditions. Unloaded start is the worst in terms of decaying time.

But today's smart controller IC's prevent this start-up oscillation by implementing on-chip soft start algorithms. This involves controlling the switch and "disturbing" the feedback network in a smart way. So the output becomes a smooth ramp-up, maybe with a slight [start-up overshoot](https://www.industrial-electronics.com/images/switchmode_1-10-2.jpg), then a stable DC.

> 3. What does the inductor waveform look like just after turn on?

I'm assuming you mean both voltage and current waveforms.

For the current, we can't ignore the start-up inrush because of empty reactive components. So the initial current will be limited by the parasitic resistances (trace resistance, DCR of the inductor, ESR of the output capacitor, etc). Again. if there's no soft-start mechanism the input current will start as a decaying oscillation. But if there's a soft-start mechanism, there's going to be a peak due to the inrush while the output rises then will be under the control i.e. normal ramp up and down.

For the voltage, it's basically the input voltage - output voltage difference. But since the output cap is empty at start up, the inductor will see full input voltage. Then, as the output rises, this difference will decrease gradually. During steady state operation the voltage will be positive (input-output difference) and negative (0 minus output voltage). So the full swing (amplitude) will be as high as input voltage.

Answer (score 4):

There's pictures on google of this. The response/graph looks different depending on the type of control parameters on it.

1. The inductor prevents the voltage from rising to Vin immediately. Turning off the input voltage at a duty-cycle is what prevents Vcap from reaching Vin ever (in a buck converter).

[image: Current and voltage waveforms under-damped]
[image]
[image]